# How can I pass two options to GCC when compiling my program?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was doing a homework assignment and I wanted to use the `<ncurses.h>`. So the `gcc filename.c -lncurses` generates an assembler output and`./a.out` executes the code. In order to avoid `***stack smashing detected***` or `segmentation fault error` I also need to execute the `gcc filename.c -fno-stack-protector`. Is there any way through which I could execute both the commands on the terminal or the code could execute the `-fno-stack-protector` command?

ps : please go easy I am a complete noob :) :P

Comment: Welcolme to SO. Check out the [help section on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). With the information you have posted, you won't get much help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you're trying to ask. What is "stack smashing detected" and these other commands?

Comment: @RSahu thankyou sir... i guess I need to rephrase my Question...

Comment: Are you just asking how to combine the `-l` and `-f` options in the same invocation of `gcc`? It should be fine to use both those options at once. It sounds like you may just need to read up on the basics of the Unix command line.

Comment: Also, `-fno-stack-protector` is a somewhat dangerous option. If you're getting stack-smashing behavior without that flag, it's almost certainly because you have a bug in your program (most likely, a buffer overrun in a stack-allocated variable).

Comment: @DanielPryden :: yes sir ... really sorry for that but precisely that is what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC can take multiple options on the command line. You should be able to pass any combination of `-f` and `-l` options, provided those options are compatible. You can get a great deal of information about the correct syntax for invoking GCC by running `man gcc` (or, on some systems, `info gcc`).

And, as I commented above, if you're getting a "stack smashing detected" error, the solution is **not** to pass `-fno-stack-protector` (which just disables the code GCC uses to detect these kind of bugs), but rather to fix the actual bug in your program that is causing the stack to get overwritten.